# DB Detection: MySQL >=5 (Auto Detected) Method: GET Type: Integer (Auto Detected)

Tags: web-server, hacking, security

Could someone please tell me which penetration-testing tool leaves behind a page that looks like this?

```
DB Detection:   MySQL >=5 (Auto Detected)
Method: GET
Type:   Integer (Auto Detected)

db_name
Table Name  Columns
table_1
table_2
table_3
table_4
table_5
table_6
table_7
```

A site one of my clients operates was recently threatened, and as proof, the hacker sent over a report that looked like the above. It looks like this was generated by an automated tool.

Could someone **point the tool out**, so that I can patch the vulnerability that is being exploited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is almost certainly output from sqlmap: http://sqlmap.org/